# Using ruby to find a word or phrase in a text file capture the word skip a line and then read the line until a blank (repeat)

Tags: ruby, parsing, text

Using ruby to find a word or phrase in a text file capture the word skip a line and then read the line until a blank (repeat)

This is a variation on a previous post with was answered with regex I want to see if it can be done with out regex.   Here is an example of the text:

```
  MATCH ME 1234

3940393  $100.00   FORTY THOUSAND THIEVES
3455     $ 00.10   ONLY 1% OF THE THIEVES

GOBBLEY GOOK: 344959904       3948820   333333333

MATCH ME

3940321  $110.00   FORTY THOUSAND RICHER PEOPLE
3        $ 00.11   ONLY 1% OF THE RICHER PEOPLE
```

The output I would like to have is this:

```
MATCH ME,1234,3940393,$100.00,FORTY THOUSAND THIEVES
MATCH ME,1234,3455,$00.10,ONLY 1% OF THE THIEVES
MATCH ME,,3940393,$110.00,FOURTY THOUSAND RICHER PEOPLE
MATCH ME,,3,$00.11,ONLY 1% OF THE RICHER PEOPLE
```

The code I have below only gets me part of the way there.  It finds the Match me but then only returns:

```
MATCH ME,1234,3940393 ,$100.00,FORTY THOUSAND THIEVES
MATCH ME,1234,3940393 ,$100.00,FORTY THOUSAND THIEVES
MATCH ME,not here,3940321 ,$110.00,FORTY THOUSAND RICHER PEOPLE
```

I am convinced my approach is wrong with the nested if's but need help with alternatives:

```
def is_numeric?(object)
  true if Float(object) rescue false
end


def is_match_me_line?(object)
true if object == "MATCH ME" rescue false
end

 def load_file
 raw_records = []
infile = File.open("match_me.txt", "r") 
while line = infile.gets

 possible_match_me = line[0,18]
  match_me_words = line[4,8]


 if is_match_me_line?(match_me_words)

 possible_match_me_number_present = possible_match_me[13,4]   
  if is_numeric?(possible_match_me_number_present)  
   fis_match_me_number = possible_match_me_number_present
   else fis_match_me_number = "not here"  
 end          

line=infile.gets  
line=infile.gets

account = line[0,8] 
amount =  line[9,7] 
description = line[19,40]
record = [match_me_words, fis_match_me_number, account, amount,description]  
raw_records << record
puts raw_records.map {|record| record*','} 

end    
end


end
load_file
```

As suggested I am trying the regex solution out but I do not get a response needed from this code:

```
File.open("text_2.txt", "r").each_line do |data|

data.scan(/(MATCH ME)(.*?)\n\n((?:(?!\n\n).)*)/m).each do |m, n, lines|
lines.each_line do |line|
puts [m, n, *line.unpack('A9A10A*')].map(&:strip).join(',')
end  
end
end
```

Comment: Honestly a regex-based solution is your best bet.

Comment: Yes. I am getting the program creep feeling and have ordered a book on it..  Just learning programming and I am finding regex is part of the scene...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's mine:

```
data.scan(/(MATCH ME)(.*?)\n\n((?:(?!\n\n).)*)/m).each do |m, n, lines|
  lines.each_line do |line|
    puts [m, n, *line.unpack('A9A10A*')].map(&:strip).join(',')
  end  
end
```

That regex is ugly, but still better than looking at 30 lines.
(?:(?!\n\n).)* means match any char that is not followed by 2 newlines. the (?:) is so it doesn't also capture the '.'

Comment: thank you again.  I am going to try this and get more educated on regex.

Comment: I am still getting a fail here - appreciate any help you can give on what I am doing wrong.  I do not get any result with the regex as is.  If I remove a /n from the first set of two then I can get the m and n printed but nothing else.

Comment: It's hard to say, there might be extra whitespace on the blank lines, in which case: \n\s*\n